# How to get the document Id from struts html property

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts-1

How to get the value of struts property bean in javascript?

Let us say i have the following code in JSP :

```
<html:checkbox property="age">
```

The property is defined in bean class :

```
private boolean age ;
```

How to get its value in javascript ?

I have done something but it doesn't help.

```
document.forms['myform'].getElementsByName('age'); //shows error 
TypeError: document.forms.getElementByName is not a function
```

What should i use in this case ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use only

```
document.getElementsByName("age");
```

**Edit:**

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    if(document.getElementsByName("age")[0].checked == true){
             //do something
          }
    });
```

Comment: if i want to check whether this checkbox is checked or not .. what should i do in this case..

Comment: No this doesn't work.. your first answer was ok. but next is not working. Showing the following error : document.getElementsByName.age is undefined

Comment: document.getElementsByName.age is undefined

Comment: I am using this in body onload ..,  i think it is same .. <body onload="checkvlaues()"> checkvalues is the function where i am checking the checkbox value .. One more thing to say i am using javascript not jquery ..

Comment: one more thing the checkbox i am using is on the parent form which is already loaded form. so i don't think we have to use document.ready in that case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54514/discussion-between-vermaraj-and-deepak-tiwari).

Comment: I think it is valid answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Another way to solve would be use the property

> **styleId**: The property that sets the ID of a tag in struts.

So you could call like this:

```
<html:checkbox property="age" styleId="age">
```

And get the element by id:

```
document.getElementById("age")
```

Comment: simple approach and it works with struts. thx mate!